# Wordpress Short code with additional parameter

Tags: shortcode, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter boostrap in my recent project . I want that the post or page content will split into columns. For doing this I am declaring several shortcode like this

```
function two_column($atts,$content=NULL){
    return ('<div class="col-md-6">'. $content .'</div>');
}
add_shortcode('two_column', 'two_column');

function three_column($atts,$content=NULL){
    return ('<div class="col-md-4">'. $content .'</div>');
}
add_shortcode('column', 'three_column');
function four_column($atts,$content=NULL){

    return ('<div class="col-md-3">'. $content .'</div>');
}
add_shortcode('four_column', 'four_column');
```

Now if I need to split content  in , then I just need to this

```
[two_column]content in first column[/two_column]
[two_column]content in second column[/two_column]
```

and so on for three or four column

But I want to make a short code like this

[column count=2]Content [/column] , I will just change the value of count , and then content will automatically split .

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Please read this:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API
Everything you need to know about shortcode parameters is in there.

Second: If you want to split content automatically into two or more columns, why don't you use css? 
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp
works pretty good.

Happy Coding,
Kuchenundkakao